# Drawing histograms or densities along smooth curves using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

Is there a general way to draw densities (violin plots) or histograms showing the distribution of `x` along a smooth `(x,y)` curve?  I use this approach to show the marginal distribution of `x` when there are multiple groups (e.g., different curves on one panel, delineated by differing colors).

Here is an example using the `Hmisc` package's `plsmo` function to get stratified loess curves and spike histograms showing the `sex`-specific data density for `age`.

```
require(Hmisc)
set.seed(1)
age <- rnorm(500, 50, 15)
y <- sample(0:1, 500, TRUE)
sex <- sample(c('female','male'), 500, TRUE)
plsmo(age, y, group=sex, col=1:2,
      datadensity=TRUE, scat1d.opts=list(nhistSpike=20))
```

[image]

Comment: How are you specifying the smooth curve? It would help to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see what your input looks like.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what plsmo is estimating and plotting. I would have imagined that you were describing a 1-d density: `densityplot(~age, groups=sex, data=dat)` for which the ggplot2 counterpart would be: `p <- ggplot( data=dat, aes( x=y, y=age, group=sex))+geom_violin(); print(p)`

Comment: `plsmo` is estimating the relationship between x and y using `lowess()` then computing elements of a high-resolution histogram for the distribution of `x` condition on the grouping variable and projecting the histogram onto the `lowess` curve(s).

Comment: I doubt you will able to achieve anything even close to this without creating your own custom function. I guess you could just modify your own `plsmo` to use use `ggplot`. `sat_smooth()` is already doing the loess part, All you left is to add the histogram just like you did in `plsmo` function

Comment: Yes I have a new function that creates a layer to add to `ggplot()` - see https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/ggplot.Predict.s.  But this function has to be provided with redundant information already known to the `ggplot` object, and the function takes the already-smoothed data instead of the raw data.  I've also created a new `geom` -- `geom_plsmo` -- to use the exceptionally fast `lowess()` but `geom_plsmo` does not add the histogram to the curves.

Comment: I have continued to enhance my function that calls `geom_segment`.  It is at https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/histSpikeg.s.  It is fully functional but does require passing some redundant information as arguments as it's not a real `geom`.

Comment: I can do it, but it is simpler to show using boxplot.  May I show how to put boxplots along your curve?  Vioplot uses boxplot-like notation.

Comment: I really want the entire data distribution.  Box plots do not capture isolated points or bimodality.  Thanks.  I've got `histSpikeg` fine-tuned now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with the ggsubplot package. See [the article](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/embedded-plots.html) and [the package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsubplot/index.html).
I believe the code will look something like:

```
qplot(age, y, data = dataset, color = sex) + 
    geom_subplot(aes(x, y, data = distributions, group = sex, 
        subplot = geom_violin(aes(x, y, data = distributions))))
```

But I don't think your example provides enough detail in your example to create the violins at points along the curves. Unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the excellent article which I read with interest.  I haven't yet been able to figure out if subplots will allow me to coordinate point-by-point with the main layer, which is need to add things like spike histograms along existing plotted curves.  I note that the article failed to reference Daniel Carr's work or thermometer plots.